# Python, Django and Threading problem

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

Greetings,
Under django 1.2 and Postgresql via psycopg2, I have a custom command that does heavy database actions (via Django ORM). I wrote it with threat pool via using the code [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187-python-thread-pool/)

Now my problem is, I get:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 136, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  connection limit exceeded for non-superusers
```

Error, how can I overcome this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You have to change your postgresql configuration file to allow more connections.

Comment: can you tell me at where? apache2 sites-enabled part or somewhere else ?

Comment: This is specific to postgresql (which is not apache !). It depends on your operating system and postgresql installation. The file should look like `postgresql.conf`

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html see the max_connections field.

Answer (score 1):

increase max_connections parameter or use a pooling daemon. max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per connection slot, plus lock space.